# Excel: Return Multiple Items with One Lookup Value but on a different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My formula works, but only if its in the same page, and along the same rows

**Formula:**

```
=(INDEX($C$1:$D$4,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$4=$F$2,ROW($C$1:$C$4)),COLUMNS(D1:D4)),2))
```

**Note:** Column G has the formula, what it does it look for value in F2 (which is 1.2) within the columns of C & D, and extracts the respective data in column D. So in this case, it would extract the data in column G.

**Question:** Now what do I do if I want this to occur from different sheets, or even different workbooks? I need to do this exact same thing, extract the data that is in column c and d  (which is on a different workbook) to my workbook.

Every time I try, I get a value error.

**Bonus:** I'm also trying to get the date that is closest to today's date, I have this formula here:

```
=IF(COUNT(G2:G5)>0,INDEX(G2:G5,MATCH(MIN(ABS(G2:G5-$D10)),ABS(G2:G5-$D10),0)),"")
```

Where D10 is just equal to `=TODAY()` and this entire formula works by pressing ctrl+shift+enter

If you can also include this into the formula so that it just spits out the closest date in G2 rather than spit out all the dates. But it is not necessary, just helps a lot.

Comment: Your formula mentions column E while there is no data in column E, Please edit your question after checking for relevance of Column E

Comment: What code are you using to pull it from a different workbook? You should use `=[WorkbookName.xlsx]SheetName!$C$2:$C$5)`. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: plus 1 just for your enthusiasm. In any event, this is a well thought out question with formula(s) that exhibit original effort. Too bad about the image of [sample data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557)

Comment: @skkakkar new formula is up, also note it only picks up starting from the second number (D3) which is weird, sorry I was pasted the other formula I was testing

Comment: Please re-test the results. [screenshot1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65565270/stackoverflow/Jun_2016/ice_screenshot_20160606-191421.jpeg)  and [screenshot2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65565270/stackoverflow/Jun_2016/ice_screenshot_20160606-191453.jpeg) This is only to encourage you to reach your goals quicker.

Answer (score 0):

For your "Closest to today problem", I was trying to spread the difference of the date or a comparison of the date just like in your example.  This is just not working out.  I solved the problem by adding another column.  I do not know if this is a valid option for you or not, but here is what I have.  Assuming H is available or you can insert a new column H. use this dragged down for each row - in your exampl 2 thorugh 5.

```
=ABS(D$10-G2)
```

Then add this in H10 or wherever you see fit

```
=D10-(MIN(H2:H5))
```

Here is an excel-ish example

```
                    5/12/2014   =ABS(D$10-G2)
                    5/13/2015   =ABS(D$10-G3)
                    5/14/2014   =ABS(D$10-G4)
                    5/15/2014   =ABS(D$10-G5)




        6/6/2016            =D10-(MIN(H2:H5))
```